# Git LFS ML Model

Tags: git, machine-learning, heroku, devops, git-lfs

I have an ML model that is 858 megaByte. I have to host my project on Heroku.

My project takes GET request, processes them using the ML model & return an output. Since the model is heavy, it can't be hosted on either GitHub or Heroku, I have used Git LFS so that the project fetches the model from `.gitattributes` file.

But I'm not sure how to call the model from `.gitattributes` file and use it in the project code.

Comment: (a) Submodules aren't "used from .gitattributes". Once they are properly cloned they're just in whatever subdirectory you put them in. (b) I'm almost positive that you can't get around Heroku's slug size limits this way. Heroku itself [doesn't support Git LFS at all](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploying-from-a-branch-besides-main): "git lfs is not supported, and using it might cause pushes to fail". What makes you think this is the right approach?

Comment: How do I host a model as big as 845 MB?

Comment: You [can request an increase in your slug size](https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller), but I don't recommend that. Another type of host might be more appropriate.